# Calculate a mean percentage

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentage

I have some percentages calculated as follows:

8/51 = 15.69
12/91 =7.19
12/167 = 13.19

Is there a way to calculate a mean percentage taking into account that the denominator differs?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Taking into account how? One of the reasons why you use percentages is to make things which are not on the same scale, on the same scale, so that you can then average them or somehow compare them. So why do you want to take into consideration the denominator, or why does it matter?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you might simply *weight* the results, for example, *(15.69 x 51 + 7.19 x 167 + 13.19 x 91) / 309* .  Which is the same as  (8+12+12) / (51+91+167) x 100 .  But it depends on what the quantities you present represent.